# Clion: setting up remote Makefile project

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

### Context

I have a remote server with C++ code and `Makefile`, and I want to use Clion's remote development + Makefile plugin to develop a Makefile project in remote.

I have mostly been following [this guide from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html) to set up remote development.

I have followed all the instructions:

1. install Makefile plugin
2. set up **Remote Host** in **Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains** ( there was no problem setting up the remote host )
3. create corresponding CMake profile in **Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake** and selected the created **Remote Host** in the **Toolchain**
4. set mapping to my newly created C++ Cmake project to the remote directory under **Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Mappings**.

---

### Problems with setup

After following all the instructions, I have two issues:

1. My local project and remote repository are out of sync. My local contains dummy files created on project initialization: `cmake-build-debug` directory, `CMakeLists.txt`, and `main.cpp`, while my remote contains code and `Makefile`.
2. There is no configuration created for me to run and build. In the top-right corner where there is `run`, `debug` and `build` buttons, no pre-created configuration is shown:

[image]

Instead, there is `Add Configuration` button. When I click `Add Configuration` and navigate to create new Makefile configuration, there is no option for me to set up project in remote.

[image]

---

### Question

So my question is:

1. Do I need `cmake-build-debug` directory and `CMakeLists.txt` even if I am only going to use the Makefile plugin to build and run? If not, how should I sink my files with remote?
2. How can I create debug and run configuration with Makefile s.t. it will only build and run on the remote host I have set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things here:

1. Full remote mode in CLion works only with CMake projects for now.
2. Makefile plugin doesn't provide Makefiles project model support in CLion (and you can't work w/o a project model in CLion, the code won't be resolved), it's for syntax highlighting in such files mostly and for Makefiles run/debug configuration. To work with makefiles in CLion, you need a workaround through the compilation database. Please check here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/managing-makefile-projects.html. But again this works only for local projects.

Comment: Thank you. Have you tried working on bazel projects on remote?

Comment: Looks like Makefile support has started landing as of CLion 2020.2 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/06/makefile-projects-in-clion/